# Integrating implicit functions

Tags: integration

Hello im getting very stuck when attempting to integrate with respect to x when iv got y variables present.

eg.

> $$\ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-80x^4}{8y^3} $$

Im sorry if my question is confusing and id be happy to explain further im just super stuck on what I need to transform y into when answering this question.

Comment: Move everything that has $y$ to the left and everything that has $x$ to the right. Then integrate left side by $y$ and right side by $x$

Answer (score 0):

Write $$8y^3dy=80x^4dx$$ and integrate.

Comment: Would that still be integrating with respect to x

Comment: The left-hand side with respect to $y$

Comment: so when integrated with respect to x it would be 8y^3 = 16x^5 + C?

Comment: This is not all, it remaines still the $dy$